# Forward port on OpenVPN server to client without redirect-gateway

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, iptables, reverse-proxy

My Setup:

On the client I have a webserver running on port 443.
The client connects to a remote server via OpenVPN.
The OpenVPN server forwards its port 443 to the client tun0 address (10.0.0.2).

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d [REMOTE_IP] -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443
```

The OpenVPN server masquerades outgoing connections from the client.

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.2/32 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If I route the whole client traffic through the vpn with `push "redirect-gateway def1"` everything is working.

But I want that the client is using the vpn only for answering the incoming connections to the webserver from the vpn. So I want to keep the original default gateway for the clients outgoing traffic.
Masquerading the traffic from the server to the client is not an option because than the webserver can't log the real IP of the incoming connections.

If I don't use `push "redirect-gateway def1"` and try to connect to the webserver from outside the OpenVPN server I can monitor only a TCP-SYN packet on the clients tun0 interface but the webserver is not answering with a TCP-ACK on any interface. I would expect at least an outgoing TCP-ACK packet on the default gateway interface.
If I try to connect from the OpenVPN server itself  (source IP 10.0.0.1) it works.

My Routing Table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
[Remote-Server] 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Is there any way to use an OpenVPN server for port forwarding without redirecting the complete traffic through the vpn?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not a really good one.

This Link helped me to solve this problem:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004295/ubuntu-server-16-04-to-2-gateway-at-same-time

On the client I add a routing table:

```
echo 1  vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

I add the OpenVPN server as default gateway to this routing table :

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev tun0 table vpn
```

I change the webserver listener port to an arbitrary hopefully rarely used port 800 and let any connection to and from this port use the new routing table "vpn":

```
ip rule add dport 800 table vpn
ip rule add sport 800 table vpn
```

Unfortunately other rules are not working. I tried following without success:

```
ip rule add to 10.0.0.0/24 table vpn
ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table vpn

ip rule add iif tun0 table vpn
ip rule add oif tun0 table vpn
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with the multiple routing tables. You just have tweak the rules you are creating a bit to make those packets use the vpn table instead of the main routing table. In my solution, I also had OpenVPN run a route-up script that set up the routes automatically upon connection.

To the OpenVPN client configuration, you can add:

```
script-security 2
route-up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
```

As you did before, add the vpn routing table:

```
echo 1  vpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Now create the script `/etc/openvpn/up.sh`. It should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 src 10.8.0.2 table vpn
/sbin/ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 table vpn
/sbin/ip rule add from 10.8.0.2 table vpn
/sbin/ip rule add to 10.8.0.2 table vpn
```

Replacing the IPs with your applicable ranges. (In this example 10.8.0.0/24 is the server configured IP range, 10.8.0.1 is the OpenVPN server, and 10.8.0.2 is the OpenVPN client.)